# DSE Schema Creation: node workload is not compatible

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am currently trying to create a graph schema for a specific node to do queries on it. I attempted to following an example shown [here](https://github.com/datastax/graph-examples/blob/master/london-tube/schema.groovy) and encountered the error stated in the title.

Property Keys Created

```
schema.propertyKey('id').Text().ifNotExists().create()
schema.propertyKey('name').Text().ifNotExists().create()
schema.propertyKey('age').Int().ifNotExists().create()
schema.propertyKey('location').Point().withGeoBounds().ifNotExists().create()
schema.propertyKey('gender').Text().ifNotExists().create()
schema.propertyKey('dob').Timestamp().ifNotExists().create()
```

The schema used is

```
schema.vertexLabel("people_node").index("search").by("name").asText().by("gender").by("location").by("dob").ifNotExists().add()
schema.vertexLabel("people_node").index("people_node_index").materialized().by("id").ifNotExists().add()
schema.vertexLabel("people_node").index("people_node_index")secondary().by("age").ifNotExists().add()
```

Example Data

```
id, name , age, location      , gender  , dob
0,  Betsy, 15 , POINT(10 15)  , F       , 1997-09-21T12:55:54+0400
```

Error Encountered

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create search index, node workdload is not compatible
```

Any advise on solving this will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start DSE with DSE Search enabled. Depending on the installation method it could be either:

- for tarball install - pass the `-s` flag to the `dse cassandra` command
- for package install - set `SOLR_ENABLED=1` in the `/etc/default/dse` file and restart service

Comment: I have installed it using OpsCenter. with 2 nodes containing DSE Search + DSE Graph and 1 node containing Cassandra + DSE Graph within the Cluster. The vertex is ingested using graph loader to the node which contains Cassandra, from there i attempted to run the codes above. I assume that search should be enabled as my cluster has nodes containing DSE Search? @Alex Ott

Comment: In the same data center, all nodes should have the same workload - so all nodes should have DSE Search + Graph enabled (Cassandra is always enabled)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Just to clarify, assuming i have 3 nodes. Does that mean that all 3 nodes must have dse search + graph enabled, while i can have cassandra enabled on 1 node only? Finally, i would like to ask if i have cassandra enabled on only 1 node does all my data i ingest gets stored into that single node only? Additionally, do overlapping functionalities(graph enabled for multiple data center e.g cassandra and dse search) from multiple datacenter have any adverse effect? @Alex Ott

Comment: Cassandra is always enabled in DSE - it's a base block that keeps all data. On top of it you can enable additional options, like, DSE Search, Graph, Analytics. They could be enabled per whole cluster, or per data centers. But inside data center, the workload always should be the same. In your case, if you enable DSE Search & Graph, all nodes also have Cassandra underneath, and store the data. You can enable Graph and Search instances in multiple DCs, but this should be done by setting replication settings when creating a graph via Gremlin

Comment: From what you wrote I understand that Cassandra will always be installed on all nodes to store data. But through installation via OpsCenter, I have attempted to access cassandra in nodes that I did not enable cassandra in and I am unable to connect via cqlsh or connect with datastax studio. On the other hand nodes that I checked cassandra I am able to log into cqlsh and connect with datastax studio. Is this the expected behavior? @Alex Ott

Comment: I'm not sure about OpsCenter - maybe it doesn't configure interfaces correctly?